# Behaviour of UpdateOnce without $set

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an old nodejs project which uses mongodb 2.2.22.
Now I want to upgrade to a newer version and stumbled over the updateOnce function without $set operator which is not working well anymore as it creates a new document every time.

As far as I can see the project always has the full object anyways but I wanted to be sure that I have as less breaking changes as possible.

The old code:
this.ownDb.collection(collectionName)).updateOne(query, update, { upsert });

Now I did not yet figure out if the behaviour of the old code is more like the
this.ownDb.collection(collectionName)).updateOne(query, { $set:update }, { upsert });

or more like
this.ownDb.collection(collectionName)).replaceOne(query, update, { upsert });

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/update/#std-label-update-command-u), an update that contains only field: value pairs is a replacement document, and will [completely replace](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/update/#update-with-a-replacement-document) the previous document.